# galois automorphism and normal (extension) of normal is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, normal-extension

Problem Statement: Given $F \subseteq L \subseteq K$ field extensions such that $K/L$ and $L/F$ are galois, and any automorphism of $L/F$ extends to an automorphism of $K$, show that $K/F$ is galois.

From the (counter) example $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$, I get the vague idea given $f$ irreducible over $F$, it may split into factors over $L$.

1. $K$ galois over $L$ means it takes certain number of these factors and its automorphisms permute roots WITHIN each of them.
2. But since automorphism of $L/F$ permutes one factor to another, the ability to extend to an automorphism of $K$ means that auto of $K$ can also permute BETWEEN these factors.

Hence $K$ does not miss roots. But how do I turn this into a solid proof? I was also thinking galois group argument...?

Comment: If the extensions are finite I think there should be a way of using the fact that $K/F$ is Galois iff its has $[K:F]$ automorphisms.

Comment: If $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ are the automorphisms of $L/F$ extended to $K$ and $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_m$ are the automorphisms of $K/L$ then it should be possible to prove that $\sigma_i\tau_j$ are all the possible $mn$ automorpshisms of $K/F$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Something like $[K:F] = [K:L][L:F] = |Gal(K/L)||Gal(L/F)|$. Now the ability to extend convert to injectively embed $Gal(L/F)$ into $Gal(K/F)$ as a subgroup $M$. Furthermore because $E$ is an normal extension, $Gal(K/E)$ is normal in $Gal(K/F)$ and therefore its product with $M$ is a subgroup. Since we always have $Gal(K/F) \leq [K:F]$ and $Gal(K/E) \cap M = 1$, size argument finishes it?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Your method is similar to my previous comment, but what is the analogy of "the product of two subgroups is asubgroup if at least one of them is normal"?

Comment: @SmoothKen you definitely can't injectively embed $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ into $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$, at least not in general. You can however embed $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ into $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$, and you can surjectively map $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ onto $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always helpful to think in terms of automorphisms.

Consider the restriction map $\mathrm{Aut}(K/F)\to \mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$.

- Since $L/F$ is Galois, this map is well-defined. Indeed, any $F$-automorphism $\sigma\colon K\to K$ restricts to a map $\sigma|_L\colon L\to K$ and, since $L/F$ is Galois, $\sigma|_L$ must have image in $L$.
- The kernel is exactly $\mathrm{Gal}(K/L)$.
- By assumption, the map is surjective.

Putting this all together with the first isomorphism theorem, we find that $|\mathrm{Aut}(K/F)| = |\mathrm{Gal}(K/L)||\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)| = [K:F]$ and the result follows.